# Autocalculate and reset in HTML & JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I am using following jsp file to adjust a value then get it squared:

```
<html>
<h4>
    <%
    int numint = 50;
    try{
      numint = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num"));
     }catch(Exception e){
      numint = 50;
     }
    %>
Adjust number: 
<form method="get">
    <br> Number (1-100): <input type="range" name="num" min="1" max="100" value=<%=numint%> >
    <br>
    <br><br> <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />  
    <br><br><input type="reset" value="Reset">  
</form>



<p><hr>
    <%  
   // Set refresh, autoload time as 5 seconds
   response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5);  //DOES NOT WORK TO AUTOCALCULATE; 

     out.println("Output: <br>"); 
     out.println("<br>Number  = "+ numint); 
     out.println("<br>Number squared = "+ numint*numint); 
    %>
    <hr>
</p>
</h4>
</html>
```

The number can be adjusted with slider and on pressing calculate button, the number and its square are shown in output area.

However, there are 2 problems:

1. The reset button does not set the number back to 50.
2. The auto-update loader does not recalculate if I just adjust the slider to some other value and wait.

How can I solve these 2 problems. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your input field has `value=<%=numint%>` which is the last submitted value.  When user hits reset, it replaces whatever he typed with that last submitted value.

Comment: Instead of a reset button you might want to have a standard button with some javascript to reset the value.  I'll put an example as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your `reset` button actually reset the value and submit the form.  Something like this code below.  Note I added an "id" to the input field.  I changed the "reset" button to actually be another submit button, with some javascript to change the input back to 50 before submitting.  You'll need to test it, may have some typos.

```
<html>
<h4>
    <%
    int numint = 50;
    try{
      numint = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num"));
     }catch(Exception e){
      numint = 50;
     }
    %>
Adjust number: 
<form method="get">
    <br> Number (1-100): <input id="num" type="range" name="num" min="1" max="100" value=<%=numint%> >
    <br>
    <br><br> <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />  
    <br><br><input type="submit" value="Reset" onclick="document.getElementById('num').value='50';">  
</form>



<p><hr>
    <%  
   // Set refresh, autoload time as 5 seconds
   response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5);  //DOES NOT WORK TO AUTOCALCULATE; 

     out.println("Output: <br>"); 
     out.println("<br>Number  = "+ numint); 
     out.println("<br>Number squared = "+ numint*numint); 
    %>
    <hr>
</p>
</h4>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks. How can I manage if there are many sliders and I have to put all of them back to mid-value with single reset button?

Comment: You can write a longer javascript function to do it.  But, the easiest solution would be to replace your reset button with a link that goes to the form without sending any values, that would effectively reset them all back to default.  To try it, replace your reset button with this: `<a href="?">Reset</a>`